# Changing the color of the <ul> in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am asking this question because I am currently struggling to understand the difference between `<ul>` and `<li>`. Till now what I have read, practiced and understood, the `<ul>` (unordered list) seems to act like a parent `<div>` in which we can place `<li>` items.

So if that's the case, then if define the color of the `<ul>` then all its children `<li>` should also have the same color.

But unfortunately, it is not working out this way. Please see it below yourself. It's only when I define the background color of `<li>` the color finally changes.
However, much surprisingly I am able to define the text color (red) in `<ul>`.
 But I am not sure why the background color (black) doesn't comes by defining in through `<ul>`?

The alternative, I know, is simple: Just define the background color black in the `<li>` element. However, I am trying to understand the reason behind this which would help me understand the definition of `<ul>` and `<li>` better.

```css
ul {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>First</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Its because `ul` height not taken properly due to `clear fix` causing by child `li` tag `float`, you can fix this with clear fix hack.

```
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

/**
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */
.cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}

ul {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

Just add .cf class to `UL` tag

```
<ul class="cf">
  <li> First </li>
</ul>
```

[CHECK JS BIN](http://jsbin.com/vazuxuhalo/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 2):

put clearfix class on ul..it will work fine..:)

```
.clearfix {
        zoom: 1;
    }
    .clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        line-height: 0;
    }
    .clearfix:after {
        clear: both;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `float` on list items and you haven't set layout on parent.
Read about hasLayout css. And using `inline-block` with `flaot` is excess. Use only one. `overflow` hidden sets layout of parent. Always set layouts of parents when you use `float`.

```css
ul {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul>
    <li> First </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

Because you are using float that's why.

Use overflow hidden in Ul just like:

```
 overflow: hidden;
```

Here is Fiddle

```
https://jsfiddle.net/zt3auduv/1/
```